# Is it possible to conditionally exclude lines of code with prepros.io?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, prepros

I've been tasked with maintaining a large codebase of client side js code that is using the revealing module pattern. A refactor is not feasible at this time, but because of the revealing module pattern vscode intellisense does not work correctly, nor do linters.

We are using prepros.io to create min files and, essentially, what I'd like to do is create import / export statements in the files and have prepros ignore those statements when creating the min file. Would something like that be possible with prepros? Yes, it's hacky, but it would be a huge quality of life improvement.

If anyone has any alternative ideas I'd love to hear them. Some quick googling showed that others in this situation seem to just stop using the revealing module pattern, but that's not an option for me at this point.